# Showing that there is always a discontinuous functional?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis

I am supposed to prove the following: Let $(V,||.||)$ be an infinite-dimensional space, then there is always a discontinuous function $T:V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$

Since continuous is equivalent to bounded for functionals, I am looking for a T such that $||T||=\infty$, right?

In this space we will find a Hamel-Basis $B$ and I assume that the vectors are normalized.

Then I take a countable subset $A=\{e_1,e_2,...\} \subset B$.

Then I set: $Te_i=2^i$
and $\forall b \in B\backslash A: Tb=0$
Then T is not bounded, since $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: |Te_n|>n|e_n|=n$.
And this should be the proof.
My question is: Does this construction always work?

Comment: What do you mean by "always work"?

Comment: for every infinite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: @OP What you have there is the standard construction of a unbounded functional. If you want to extend it to a general TVS, the questions is whether $B$ can be taken to be bounded.

Comment: What do you mean by TVS?

Comment: A general topological vector space where the topology is not necessarily given by a norm.

Comment: Yes, this is correct but: don't forget that you started with a normed vector space, not just an vector space, and that you need to extent $T$ to $V$ by linearity. Also $Te_n:=n$ would do the trick just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you have to construct a **linear** functional. Your $T$ is not linear, but the construction of a linear one is similar.

Comment: why is my functional not linear?

Comment: Because $0 = T(e_1 +e_2) \ne T(e_1)+T(e_2) = 2 + 4 = 6$.

Comment: $e_1+e_2$ is not in $B$. The OP is correct but just omitted to mention that one extends that from $B$ to $V$ by linearity.

Comment: Oh, right. I thought $B$ is the whole space and not only the Hamel basis. I will delete my "answer" soon.

Comment: Please edit the answer instead of deleting it; we have enough "unanswered"  questions as is.